# SQL Queries on Table with "Forest" structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using  `MySQL 5.5`. Suppose I have an SQL table that has an "N-forest" structure as follows:

```
create table foo
(
    id int not null primary key,
    parent_id int,
    bar varchar(255),

    foreign key (parent_id) references foo (id)
)
```

If `parent_id` is `null` it signifies a root element.  Also we guarantee it is acyclic.

I now want to select the row with `id` `@x` and all of its descendants (that is the set containing row with id @x and recursively any rows that have a parent_id in this set) sorted in pre-order:

```
select * from foo where parent_id=DescendantOf(@x) sort by Preorder
```

What SQL statement can I use? (modifications to table structure allowed if needed)

Also I would like to find the root id of a given element:

```
select RootOf(@x) from foo
```

How can I do that?

Can MySQL handle this efficiently or do I need to maintain my own index or auxillary table?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such functonality in MySQL built-in... Oracle has a feature called "hierarchical query" which does what you want...

In MySQL You can implement/simulate it although the "how" is rather complex - for a very good walkthrough see [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Comment: Actually it's not only Oracle. Many major DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird, DB2, SQL Server, Teradata) support hierarchical queries nowadays through "*recursive common table expressions*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are absolutely right... I just referred to Oracle since MySQL is now owned by Oracle...